# R: plotting pdf in a certain interval

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a probability function in a certain interval. The x-axes has to be longer than the interval because there are more pdf's in one plot. 
But with the growing of the x-axes, the pdf generating data too, although the code implied the certain interval. 
Code:

```
 p1 <- ggplot() +
 stat_function(data=data.frame(x=c(2,30)),aes(x),fun = dnorm, n = 101, 
 args= list(mean=5,sd=1),color="black")+
 xlim(-5,80)+
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)
```

the pdf in p1 generate data until x=80. But x values in the code are in a vector until x=30.
How could I prevent that the pdf produces values until 80 or how have to be the code that the distribution stops at x=30?

Comment: Hey Brian I tried your code with following function: `dTDF<-function(x,g,a,b,k){
  
  exp(-exp(-(x/a)+((a*k)/(g-x))-b))*(exp(-(x/a)+((a*k)/(g-x))-b))*((1/a)-((a*k)/((g-x)^2)))
  
}` inside `geom_line(data=data_frame(x=seq(2500,11300, 0.25), y = dTDF(x,g=11263,a=1185, b=-4, k=-0.5),
            aes(x, y),  color = "red"))`     an error occurs that the variable don't have the same length. Why it works for dnorm but not with my function?

Comment: it looks like you're missing a parenthesis inside `geom_line`, to close the `data_frame(...)` call. With something so complex, you probably should generate the data outside `ggplot` and just call it in the `data =` statement. Also, you certainly don't need steps of `0.25` inside `seq(...)` with numbers of that scale, try replacing it with `100`.

Comment: See my further update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can construct a dataframe with the only the x-values you want plotted on the fly using `dplyr::data_frame`. I added another *p.d.f.* to demonstrate that the way you want it presented will work.

```
library(dplyr)
# to use data_frame

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=data_frame(x=seq(2,30, 0.25), y = dnorm(x, mean = 5, sd = 1)),
            aes(x, y),  color = "black") +
  geom_line(data=data_frame(x=seq(40,70, 0.25), y = dnorm(x, mean = 60, sd = 5)),
            aes(x, y),  color = "red") +
  xlim(-5,80)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

### Update

You can also label them like so, by moving the `color=` inside the `aes(...)`:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=data_frame(x=seq(2,30, 0.25), y = dnorm(x, mean = 5, sd = 1)),
            aes(x, y,  color = "mean:5, sd:1")) +
  geom_line(data=data_frame(x=seq(40,70, 0.25), y = dnorm(x, mean = 60, sd = 5)),
            aes(x, y,  color = "mean:60, sd:5")) +
  xlim(-5,80)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("mean:5, sd:1" = "black",
                                "mean:60, sd:5" = "red"))
```

[image]

### Update2

Your density function works for me.

```
dTDF<-function(x,g,a,b,k){
  exp(-exp(-(x/a)+((a*k)/(g-x))-b))*(exp(-(x/a)+((a*k)/(g-x))-b))*((1/a)-((a*k)/((g-x)^2)))
  } 

df1 <- data_frame(x=seq(2500,11300, 100), 
                  y = dTDF(x,g=11263,a=1185, b=-4, k=-0.5))
df2 <- data_frame(x=seq(7000,14300, 100), 
                  y = dTDF(x,g=15263,a=1105, b=-10, k=-0.5))


ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x, y))+ 
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x, y)) +
  xlim(1000, 15000)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Brian I tried your code with following function: