# How to hatch an interval of a function made with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a probability density function using ggplot2 and stat_function but I wanted to hatch the area P(0,5<X<1,5) and have no idea how to do it, does anybody know? Here's my code:

`fx <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-0.5,2.5)), aes(x=x))+ stat_function(fun=function(x){ifelse(between(x,0,2),1-(0.5*x),0)},color="blue",lwd=1,fill)`

Also if you know how to hatch 2 differents intervals of the function would help me very much (0<x<0,5 and 0,5<X<1,5 for example).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. a helpful way for you to search is to type `[r] what I want to know` in the search box above. For your current question, this might address [create and plot probability density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059653/r-plotting-pdf-in-a-certain-interval). HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xlim` arguments of `stat_function()` to limit the function to a range. If you combine that with a `geom = "area"`, you can fill in different regions.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(x){ifelse(between(x,0,2),1-(0.5*x),0)}

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-0.5,2.5)), aes(x=x))+ 
  stat_function(fun=fun, xlim = c(0, 0.5), fill = "green",
                geom = "area") +
  stat_function(fun=fun, xlim = c(0.5, 1.5), fill = "red",
                geom = "area") +
  stat_function(fun=fun,color="blue",lwd=1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>